# WebSharper Interface Generator - Records

Tags: f#, websharper

How do I go about defining a record that would be serialized to a JSON object... I've been trying to build the oConfig parameter for YUI2 constructor, something like:

```
type TreeParameter =
    {
        Type : string
        Label : string
        Expanded : bool
        Children : TreeParameter array
    }
```

Thanks!

David

Comment: I don't know of a way to serialize to JSON automatically, but you can just override the ToString() method, for example

Comment: This is really about the WebSharper interface generator, I assume it would have special operators for defining such a type.

Comment: I do not see a single example of records being generated in the Bing map extensions located here: https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/ifpub-ws-bing/src I'm starting to think it's simply not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we could implement this but it has not yet made it into the interface generator. For now you can do:

```
let TreeParameter =
    let self = Type.New()
    Pattern.Config "TreeParameter" {
        Required =
            [
                "Type", T<string>
                "Label", T<string>
                "Expanded", T<bool>
                "Children", Type.ArrayOf self
            ]
        Optional = []
    }
    |=> self
```

From F# point of view the generated type will look like this:

```
type TreeParameter(t: string, l: string, e: bool, c: TreeParameter[]) =
    member this.Type = t
    member this.Label = l
    member this.Expanded = e
    member this.Children = c
```

From JavaScript perspective, the values would look like this:

```
{Type:t,Label:l,Expanded:e,Children:c}
```

In essence it is like a record without the benefit of record syntax and functional extension.

Answer (score 1):

WebSharper has now implemented this feature. Just use `TSelf`.

Example:

```
let TreeParameter =
    Pattern.Config "TreeParameter" {
        Required =
            [
                "Type", T<string>
                "Label", T<string>
                "Expanded", T<bool>
                "Children", Type.ArrayOf TSelf
            ]
        Optional = []
    }
```